# Client error: automated custom google search with R

Tags: r, google-api, automation, google-custom-search

I access the Google Custom Search API via `googleAuthR` using the `httr` package to automatically search Google for randomly created strings, e.g. numbers. My contingents are 100 searches per second and 10.000 searches a day. I create a list and send my requests, such as:

```
random.search.string<- function(n = 10000)
    {randomNumbers <- c(1:n)
    for (i in 1:n)
    {randomNumbers[i] <- paste(sample(0:9, 9), collapse = "")}
    return(randomNumbers)}

mydata<-cbind.data.frame(as.factor(random.search.string()))
mydata[ , 2]<- c(1:length(random.search.string()))
```

Using this dataframe, I create the queries:

```
cs1<-"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="
API_Key<-"myAPI-Key"
ENGINE_ID<-"mySecret"
cs2<-"&googlehost=.de&num=1"

query <- vector()
for (i in mydata[, 2]) query[i] <- paste(cs1, API_Key, "&cx=", ENGINE_ID, "&q=", mydata[i, 1], cs2, sep = "")
```

I receive the output via:

```
output<-list()
for (k in query) {output[k] <- content(GET(k))$items[[1]]$link[1]; flush.console(); Sys.sleep(0.5)}
```

The output contains all links of searches that had a result. However, sometimes the dashboard of the Google APIs indicates client errors (403): dailyLimitExceeded - although the API Manager indicates that I am about a hundred queries under my daily limit. Any suggestions how to fix that?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: please edit your question and include the full error message returned by google (4xx) is not enough to identify the problem.

Comment: Can you tell me where to get the full error mesage? The dashboard onlyy provides an overview: response code: search.cse.list; client error(4xx): 559; server error: 2 - numbers are the absolute N of incidents.

Comment: again that's not the google error it shouldn't have xxx we need to know the full message google is returning to you.

Comment: Do I get the error message at the frontend (API-Manager; if yes, do you know where?) or do I have to retrieve it from R? Again mentioning that at the moment I am only saving the mere link of the first result (without any further information).

Comment: Alright, I found out that I have to retrieve the message from the output. I updated the question. Thanks to DalmTo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
        "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
  }
}
```

If you are getting the daily limit error then this basically means that you have made the max number of requests for that day.   The quota will reset at mid night West cost USA time.

If you go to the Google Developer console under Library find the API you enabled look for the Quotas tab.  You can increase the daily quota on some of the Google API. Click the little pencil on the side to increase it

[image]

Note: Google is not perfect with calculating your quota.  You can be plus or minus a few hundred.

Comment: Thank you. I already set the quota to 10.000 a day.  The imperfectness of the calculation of the quota, however, causes these errors.